# I try to add passwords to the "pass" password manager. But my attempts fail with "no public key" GPG errors. Why?

Tags: password, utilities, gpg

I am trying to install [Pass: the standard Unix password manager](http://zx2c4.com/projects/password-store/), however, when I try to add passwords to the appliation I get these errors

```
gpg: Kelly's Passwords: skipped: No public key
gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: No public key
```

#### GPG Public Keys?

When I type in the command `gpg --list-keys` I get:

```
/home/khays/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
------------------------------
pub   2048R/64290B2D 2012-11-05
uid                  Kelly Hays <hays.kelly@gmail.com>
sub   2048R/0DF57DA8 2012-11-05
```

I am a little lost of how to remedy this, any ideas?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

How did you create the password store? `pass init "Kelly's Passwords"`? If so, this is wrong, you should have called `pass init 64290B2D`.

And if then `pass insert foo` will fail with:

```
gpg: fooo: skipped: public key not found
gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: public key not found
```

then you have to trust your own key first (`gpg --edit-key 64290B2D`, `trust`, `5`, `save`).

Comment: I'll just add for those who were one step behind like me, you should first init gpg key with `gpg --generate-key`

Comment: @ItayB the command to generate a gpg key is actually `gpg --gen-key` (in gpg 1.4.20)

Comment: In one case, using `gpg` (version 1.4.20) under Xubuntu, leads always to failures (generating passwords via `pass`). Using `gpg2` (version 2.1.11) made everything work fine.

Comment: The 'key', eg 64290B2D, is whatever you used to identify the key, in my case being an email address, revealed as uid with `gpg -k`

Comment: Not working to me, I get `gpg: foo: skipped: No public key`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/676444/gpg-error-retrieving-email-via-wkd-no-data-when-trying-credential-storage

Answer (score 6):

With the same indications, if anyone stumbles across this issue, the solution may be bit different. Your `pass` is using `gpg2` instead of `gpg`, you might  have used to generate/manage your keys (or, vice-versa). Verify with:

```
bash -x $(which pass) insert foo
```

Comment: In case one has already generated a with GPG 1 - you can import it into GPG 2 like this: `gpg2 --import ~/.gnupg/secring.gpg`

Comment: Yes thanks, my `pass` is indeed using `gpg2`.

Answer (score 6):

This is a **rollup** of the above information as I used it for `pass` with `gpg2` on Kubuntu 20.04 (Ubuntu Linux v 20.04 with KDE desktop)

`pass` is the Linux CLI password manager.

**High Level View:**
`pass` requires that you have a public `gpg` key. `gpg` is a Linux CLI encryption program. There are several versions. Kubuntu 20.04 uses `gpg2` but  just calls it "gpg".

You will first have to create a `gpg` key. Then you pass the key-id to `pass` as an argument. After which it *should* work.

Generate the key:

`~$ gpg --gen-key`

Have a look at your shiny new key:

`~$ gpg --list-keys`

```
pub   rsa3072 2022-07-17 [SC] [expires: 2024-07-16]
      YourKey (a bunch of letters and numbers)
uid           [trust-level] yourName <yourAddress@email.com>
sub   rsa3072 2022-07-17 [E] [expires: 2024-07-16]
```

You have to tell your machine to trust your new key:

`gpg --edit-key yourName yourAddress@email.com, trust, 5, save)`

(this step actually wasn't necessary for me, because the trust was automatically set to [ultimate] - but doing this step didn't hurt me.)

From this point forward you can move forward with the `pass` page at:
https://www.passwordstore.org/

------ this is what it looked like for me setting up a password for docker in a folder called 'dev' -------------------

Initialize the password store:

```
~$ pass init yourAddress@email.com
Password store initialized for yourAddress@email.com
```

Create the password store:

```
~$ pass insert dev/docker
mkdir: created directory '/home/$USER/.password-store/dev'
Enter password for dev/docker: 
Retype password for dev/docker:
```

Did I enter the correct password? -

```
~$ pass dev/docker
thisIsTheWrongPassword!
```

Remove the wrong password -

```
~$ pass rm dev/docker
Are you sure you would like to delete dev/docker? [y/N] y
removed '/home/$USER/.password-store/dev/docker.gpg'
```

Enter the correct password

```
~$ pass insert dev/docker
mkdir: created directory '/home/$USER/.password-store/dev'
Enter password for dev/docker: 
Retype password for dev/docker:
```

Check if password is correct second time-

```
~$ pass dev/docker
doNotExposeYourPasswordOnStackExchange!
```

I can use pass to login to Docker Hub via CLI

```
pass dev/docker | login -u myUserName --password-stdin
```

This pipes the password directly to Docker Hub without printing it to screen.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error for while, running the bash in debug is helping. ( bash -x ), I then realized that pass had listed a non-existing gpg-key in .password-store/.gpg-id

Answer (score 3):

Remember `pass init <gpg-id>` used to Initialize new password storage and use gpg-id for encryption. Which you only generate for the **first time** only.

Whereas `pass add <folder/file>`  is used to add a new password inside the above password storage.

```
$ pass init tsabunkar (storage-manager should be done first time only)
$ pass add personal/gmail (adding my gmail creds)
```

Now If you want to add another credential, but rather than :

```
$ pass add personal/linux
```

Now again you want to add another credentials, but this time you had used `init` command instead of `add`

```
$ pass init personal/aws/root
```

but later you realized that option should have been `add`

```
$ pass add personal/aws/root
```

Error Message:

```
Enter password for personal/aws/root: 
Retype password for personal/aws/root: 
gpg: personal/aws/root: skipped: No public key
gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: No public key
Password encryption aborted.
```

I guess now you understand this is because you are referencing to wrong **password-store** which should have been **tsabunkar** but not **personal/aws/root**
Therefore to re-referencing back to the correct password-store solves this issue:

```
$ pass init tsabunkar
$ pass add personal/aws/root
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, but checking with `gpg2 --list-keys` gives me

```
pub   rsa4096/0x12345678 2016-11-22 [SC] [expired: 2018-11-26]
```

So my solution is to

```
gpg --edit-key 0x12345678
gpg> expire
...
gpg> save
```

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177310/14315

If you have to renew subkeys use this:

```
> e.g. if the subkey whose validity you want to extend is the first listed
> subkey, or if it is the only listed subkey, then the  command would be
> Command> key 1
> this will put a * after the word sub, indicating that this particular
> subkey has been selected. then
> Command> expire
> and follow the prompts.
```

Source https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2005-June/026063.html

If you get another error while using expire like:

> part of private key missing

Try using gpg2 instead of gpg.