# Why did `pass` stop working after key renewal?

Tags: linux, gpg

Can anyone advise why my [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/) password manager stopped working? As far as I know it was perfectly ok before I renewed an expired key. Accessing old passwords still works fine, but I can no longer create new passwords.

```
$ pass generate foo
gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: No public key
Password encryption aborted.
```

Here is the output of `gpg --list-keys`.

```
pub   rsa4096 2019-05-12 [SC] [expires: 2022-05-11]
      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      uid           [ultimate] XXXXXXXXXX  <xxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.com>
      sub   rsa4096 2019-05-12 [E] [expires: 2020-05-25]
```

And `gpg --version`:

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.20
libgcrypt 1.8.5
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

I began using `pass` last year, when I was running Linux Mint 19. I'm now running Ubuntu Studio 19.10, using the same `/home` partition, for what that's worth.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412363/412280, I found that `~/.password-store/.gpg-id` contained only the name of a botched password entry. I replaced  `~/.password-store/.gpg-id` with my real gpg-id and all is good again.

Comment: Can confirm i had that same problem a lot before. I would recommend to backup not only the password-store directory (since it's a git directory, using `git bundle` is a good idea) but also the `.gpg-id` along the `.gnupg` directory.